# How to install android sdk in latest android studio

Tags: android

I am new to android and I need android sdk in my gluon project. In latest release of android studio , the android sdk is not bundled up with android studio. So, I downloaded the sdk tools only(zip). I tried all the ways mentioned on stack overflow to run sdkmanager, but every trick failed. Isn't there any simple way of getting android sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Open android studio and go to the following path then you can download your SDK tools:
file -> settings -> appearance and behavior --> system settings --> android sdk